# intelligent web crawler using machine learning

Tags: text-mining, named-entity-recognition

I am building e commerce site

**Problem Statement**:

I want to crawl web pages to `get product name, images and product specifications/features` and store it in my `database`

**Input to machine learning algorithm**:

Web page with html content

**Output expected from machine learning algo**:

- It should automatically detect whether it's product details page or not
- If it's product details page then it should recognize product category
- Then it should parse product name, specifications

**Question**

Which algorithm would be suitable for this problem statement?

Can anyone suggest proper approach to follow?

Comment: ...and the question is?

Comment: @dratewka updated question , sorry for that

Comment: @AkashShinde did you get solution to your question.

Comment: @swan no not yet

Comment: did you tried this framework..https://scrapy.org/

Comment: yes, I ended up scraping web page, but I had to implement own custom logic to parse each web page.I used scrapy library only to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in Machine Learning/Naturel Language Processing but my gut feeling says it is very difficult to fully implement this as an ML product. 
So first look at whether your targeted eCommercise sites provides some kind of API to extract data. If such APIs are available use those and that will be rally easy than using ML.